# How to use RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry?

Tags: spring, spring-amqp

I wanted to destory my specific RabbitListener...
So I searched and most of people used this way.

```
@Autowired
RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry endpointRegistry;

endpointRegistry.getListenerContainer( "listener_id" ).stop();
```

But endpointRegistry didn't have any container...
endpointRegistry.getListenerContainers().size() = 0

And I also made a Bean like this in RabbitMqConfiguration.

```
@Bean
@Qualifier( "RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry" )
public RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry(){
        return new RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry();
    }
```

how to fix it ???

```
@Autowired
RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry endpointRegistry;

endpointRegistry.getListenerContainer( "listener_id" ).stop();


@Bean
@Qualifier( "RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry" )
public RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry(){
        return new RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to declare your own `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` - the framework does that for us via `RabbitBootstrapConfiguration`, when `@EnableRabbit` is provided on a `@Configuration`.

Then your `@RabbitListener` with that `listener_id` is going to be registered into that global registry and somewhere at runtime you will be able to stop it.

Comment: I'm sorry to reply late. I understood this way. 
but how to get global registry?  
when I used RabbitListenerEndPointRegistry, java throw the error that `There is no bean of RabbitListenerEndPointRegistry`

Comment: I resolved this problem by your way! Thank you very much:)

just extends RabbitBootstrapConfiguration

Answer (score 1):

As @Artem said you don't have to do this, simplly autowaire it.

I had a task to shutdown the producer everyday from 11:00 pm to 12:01 am, So I used Spring-RabbitMQ with Scheduling to stop or start all Listener containers as below.

**Note that, This is just illustration and you do not have to follow my case**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedualingConfig {
    
    public static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchedualingConfig.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry;
    
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 23 * * *")
    public void stopAll() {
        rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers().forEach(container -> {
            log.info("stop listener containers...");
            container.stop();
        });
    }
    
    @Scheduled(cron = "1 0 0 * * *")
    public void startAll() {
        rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers().forEach(container -> {
            log.info("start listener containers...");
            container.start();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can stop/start the registry itself; it will act on each registered container.